# How to insert a component into a lightning: datatable component row

Tags: lightning, lightning-datatable

I need to create a table and would like to use the ligthingdatatable component. In jqueryDataTable I can put an inline component in the table. But how do I do this for lightning: datatable?

Comment: As per the [roadmap](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_components_roadmap.htm&r=https:%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5), it's supposed to available now. Did anybody figure out how? I couldn't find any documentation yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Only the supported data types can be placed in a lightning:datatable, and custom components isn't one of them. Instead, you'd have to implement your own components using the Lightning Design System.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we can do this with LWC version of the datatable but not the aura version as per documentation(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation).

Check out the section titled "Creating Custom Data Types".